# Apply each function to each element of a list Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a list of a function like this:

> [(+1), (+2), (*4), (^2)]

And i want to apply each function to each element of an another list. For example i have a list like this [1..5], i want to get this as result: [2,4,12,16]

This is what i tryed already.

```
applyEach :: [(a -> b)] -> [a] -> [b]
applyEach _ [] = []
applyEach (x:xs) (y:ys) = x y : applyEach xs ys
```

I don't know what is the problem, we have a online surface where we have to place the code and it test our submision, and only said that my code isn't pass.

Comment: homework? in this order, do: 1. look for answers or hints in the course materials that were certainly provided, 2. discuss with your fellow students, 3. ask your instructor.

Comment: There's already a function that does exactly that in the standard libraries. Though I suppose it's at a higher level of abstraction than you're currently used to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your function works fine when the lists are the same length, or when the second list is shorter than the first:

```
> applyEach [(+1), (+2), (*4), (^2)] [1..4]
[2,4,12,16]
> applyEach [(+1), (+2), (*4), (^2)] [1..3]
[2,4,12]
```

But you're not dealing with the case where the second list is longer, as it is in your example:

```
> applyEach [(+1), (+2), (*4), (^2)] [1..5]
[2,4,12,16*** Exception: H.hs:(2,1)-(3,47): Non-exhaustive patterns in function applyEach
```

You need to add one more equation to your function to handle this case.

Comment: Ohhh well, really i forgot to add this case applyEach [] _  = [], thank you, you saved my life =)

Answer (score 6):

You can also do this with the built-in `zipWith` function and the `$` operator:

```
applyEach fs xs = zipWith ($) fs xs
```